# Pandas dt accessor returns wrong day and month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

My  CSV data looks like this -

```
Date      Time
1/12/2019 12:04AM
1/12/2019 12:09AM
1/12/2019 12:14AM
```

and so on

And I am trying to read this file using pandas in the following way -

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 



data = pd.read_csv('D 2019.csv',parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])
print(data['Date_Time'].dt.month)
```

When I try to access the year through the dt accessor the year prints out fine as 2019.
But when I try to print the day or the month it is completely incorrect. In the case of month it starts off as 1 and ends up as 12 when the right value should be 12 all the time.

With the day it starts off as 12 and ends up at 31 when it should start at 1 and end in 31. The file has total of 8867 entries. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default format is MM/DD, while yours is DD/MM.

The simplest solution is to set the `dayfirst` parameter of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **`dayfirst`** : DD/MM format dates, international and European format (default `False`)

```
data = pd.read_csv('D 2019.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']], dayfirst=True)
#                                                                -------------
```

```
>>> data['Date_Time'].dt.month
# 0    12
# 1    12
# 2    12
# Name: Date_Time, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning `format` argument of `pd.to_datetime`

```py
df = pd.read_csv('D 2019.csv')
df["Date_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_Time"], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%p')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the data type of your dataframe and convert the column "Date" into datetime

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
```

After you can access the day, month, or year using:

```
dt.day
dt.month
dt.year
```

Note: Make sure the format of the date (D/M/Y or M/D/Y)

**Full Code**

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

data = pd.read_csv('D 2019.csv')
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])

print(data["Date"].dt.day)
print(data["Date"].dt.month)
print(data["Date"].dt.year)
```

Comment: I edited the answer, please check now